# Dynamically autosize DIV on resolution change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I I have div. Inside of this div, i placed countdown timer. I need to make it responsive. It is responsive if I refresh page after I resolution change( if changeing browser size and setting exact resolution ), but when you zoom page or changing my browser size it is keeping same big size. Here is picture:
[picture of countdown while i am zooming](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBXSc.jpg)

```js
var timer,
  $win = $(window);

$win.on('resize', function() {
  clearTimeout(timer);
  timer = setTimeout(function() {
    $("#DateCountdown").height($win.height());
  }, 500);

});
$("#DateCountdown").TimeCircles({
  "animation": "smooth",
  "bg_width": 0.5,
  "fg_width": 0.03,
  "circle_bg_color": "#111111111",
  "time": {
    "Days": {
      "text": "Дней",
      "color": "#FFCC66",
      "show": true
    },
    "Hours": {
      "text": "Часов",
      "color": "#99CCFF",
      "show": true
    },
    "Minutes": {
      "text": "Минут",
      "color": "#BBFFBB",
      "show": true
    },
    "Seconds": {
      "text": "Секунд",
      "color": "#ff8080",
      "show": true
    }
  }
});

(function($) {
```

```css
/**
 * This element is created inside your target element
 * It is used so that your own element will not need to be altered
 **/

.time_circles {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}


/**
 * This is all the elements used to house all text used
 * in time circles
 **/

.time_circles>div {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
}


/**
 * Titles (Days, Hours, etc)
 **/

.time_circles>div>h4 {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 11pt;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Century Gothic', Arial;
  line-height: 1;
}


/**
 * Time numbers, ie: 12
 **/

.time_circles>div>span {
  color: #ffffff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Century Gothic', Arial;
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="background-color: rgba(69,63,38,.4);backdrop-filter: blur(10px);width: 80%;margin: 3em auto 0;">
  <div style="text-align:center;font-size:3vw;color:white">До следующего урожая осталось</div>
  <div id="DateCountdown" data-date="2017-07-06 00:00:00" style="width: 100%"></div>
</div>
```

Here is script for width and height which is working onload. How to do it dynamically without refresh

```js
        // Determine the needed width and height of TimeCircles
        var height = this.element.offsetHeight;
        var width = this.element.offsetWidth;
        if (height === 0)
            height = $(this.element).height();
        if (width === 0)
            width = $(this.element).width();

        if (height === 0 && width > 0)
            height = width / this.data.drawn_units.length;
        else if (width === 0 && height > 0)
            width = height * this.data.drawn_units.length;
        
        // Create our canvas and set it to the appropriate size
        var canvasElement = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvasElement.width = width;
        canvasElement.height = height;
        
        // Add canvas elements
        this.data.attributes.canvas = $(canvasElement);
        this.data.attributes.canvas.appendTo(this.container);
        
        // Check if the browser has browser support
        var canvasSupported = isCanvasSupported();
        // If the browser doesn't have browser support, check if explorer canvas is loaded
        // (A javascript library that adds canvas support to browsers that don't have it)
        if(!canvasSupported && typeof G_vmlCanvasManager !== "undefined") {
            G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(canvasElement);
            limited_mode = true;
            canvasSupported = true;
        }
        if(canvasSupported) {
            this.data.attributes.context = canvasElement.getContext('2d');
        }

        this.data.attributes.item_size = Math.min(width / this.data.drawn_units.length, height);
        this.data.attributes.line_width = this.data.attributes.item_size * this.config.fg_width;
        this.data.attributes.radius = ((this.data.attributes.item_size * 0.8) - this.data.attributes.line_width) / 2;
        this.data.attributes.outer_radius = this.data.attributes.radius + 0.5 * Math.max(this.data.attributes.line_width, this.data.attributes.line_width * this.config.bg_width);
```

Comment: can you add more code? in your example, the timer is empty. From a simple guess, i would say that the div #DateCountdown resizes well, but the timer elements might be fixed size, so they don't change.

Comment: can you add css specific to timer

Comment: @Kaddath JS file is little big. If it is fixed why it changes if refresh page?

Comment: @Puneet I added css code of timer

Comment: they are probably fixed by javascript at the page loading. It they were in % they would resize every time. I see that you already use `$win.on('resize',...)` to adapt height, you just have to find how the elements are width sized on creation or page load, and add it in your function. Note that for mobile support, it is also good to bind it to the `orientationchange` event

Comment: @Kaddath exactly that what i need to know, need functon which adopt for each width. fo **orientationchange** is this code okay `$(document).on("pagecreate",function(event){
  $(window).on("orientationchange",function(){
  
  });                     
});`?

Comment: i think jQuery's orientationchange exists only in jQuery mobile, not the standard one, in case you have to use `window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function() { })`. Note that all this implementation also depends on how the elements are originally resized (based on dimensions in px? a more flexible way?)

Comment: @Kaddath I just noticed that in orientation change my responsive div is crushes also with height.

Comment: what do you mean by "crushes"? welcome to the mobile device support, where on some devices window height and witdth are messed up on orientation change. I don't have all my resources here, if i have time tonight i'll share some scripts i wrote. My advice: solve all the problems with desktop first

Comment: @Kaddath here you can see webpage. 
[http://craftovdvlp.club/](http://craftovdvlp.club/)
Crushes i mean that it is not working right. On zoom, height of div is not working correct, it is increasing and not decreasing back. you can see it from my link.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the window onresize event for this.

Check here for reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onresize

Simple code example:

```
var onResizeHandler = function() {
    // add your resize handling here
}

window.onresize = onResizeHandler;
```

Click **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/wilt/70hyufny/)** to see this example in action.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I see that this script wotking onto detect width and height. My countdown is getting required size on refresh. I need that div do it  automaticaly without refresh.
`<p id="example"></p>` and JS
`function myFunction() {
    var w = window.outerWidth;
    var h = window.outerHeight;
    var txt = "Window size: width=" + w + ", height=" + h;
    document.getElementById("example").innerHTML = txt;
}`

Comment: @Orik3ll0 Yes, so if you need to do it automatically without refresh you can use this listener to execute the function with your resize logic. It works for both zooming and resizing. I don't really see what the problem is. Can you be more clear?

Comment: Can you give me more clear example how it is working please?